# Looking for opposite expression to "She looks twice her age"

Tags: phrase-request, antonyms

> She looks **twice** her age.

How to express the opposite of the sentence above, i.e. the fact that she has youthful appearance. Is it "She looks twice less her age"?

Comment: Uh...this isn't obvious?

Comment: The opposite is clearly "her age looks twice her!"

Comment: Anything relating to age can backfire. By noticing this 'fact' you are also saying that they are not young. Instead a compliment to their energy/aura/presences/personality is more likely to convey the message while respecting the life lived.

Comment: I refuse to upvote anything here, since as @bye says the answrer should be perfectly obvious. An interesting thing would be to know of similar expressions in other languages - that differ in some way from the English.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> She looks **half** her age.

Examples:

> [Janet Jackson, 49, **Looks Half Her Age** in New Album Photo Shoot](http://uk.eonline.com/news/688658/janet-jackson-49-looks-half-her-age-in-new-album-photo-shoot-watch-a-behind-the-scenes-video) (a headline)
>
> She may be 46 but Jennifer Lopez **looks half her age** in her latest jewellery campaign. ([Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-3183826/Jennifer-Lopez-46-looks-young-years-showcases-timeless-skin-new-Endless-Jewelry-campaign.html))